# How to get sum consecutive array elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a array with 4 element. I want to get a new array which calculates the sum of array elements where number of opereands increases one at a time.

For example I have an array `[1000, 2000, 2000, 4000]`. 
Result array should be like

```
[ 1000, 1000 + 2000, 1000 + 2000 + 2000, 1000 + 2000 + 2000 + 4000]
```

i.e [1000, 3000, 5000, 9000]

```js
var array = [1000, 2000, 2000, 4000];

var newArray = array.map((e,i) => e)

console.log(newArray);
```

Is there any way to do that using map function ? Or any other way ?

Comment: var numbers1 = [1000, 2000, 2000, 4000];
var numbers2 = numbers1.map(myFunction)
function myFunction(value, index, array) {
 var i= 0;
 while (index > i) {
 index--;
 value = value + array[index];
 }  
 return value ;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    const array = [1000, 2000, 2000, 4000];
    const result = array.reduce((acc,item, index) => { 
      if (index === 0) { acc.push(item); }
      else {
        acc.push(acc[index-1] + item);
      }
      return acc;
    } ,[]);
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through you original array and before you add the value to your new Array, add the last Value of the new Array to it.

```js
var array = [1000, 2000, 2000, 4000];

var newArray = [];
for(n of array){
  if(newArray.length>0) newArray.push(newArray[newArray.length-1]+n)
  else newArray.push(n)
}

console.log(newArray);
```